# Which DataViz Python package for sentences clusters visualisation?

Tags: python, package, visualization, cluster-analysis

I have created an algorithm that create clusters of similar sentences and extract important words. I want to create a Viz that shows (dynamically if possible) clusters, sentences included in those clusters and the important words of the selected cluster.

I have seen about pyLDAvis but it doesn't seem to be good for personalisation of data displayed.

Do you know any package that could help me ?

Thank you,